# Merge columns of pageblocksection for only one row

Tags: visualforce

I have a pageblocksection with `columns="2"` and it displays a few outputfields. I also want to show a pageblocktable in the same section so when the section is collapsed this pageblocktable also collapses. 
Now the pageblock table width is restricted upto only the 1 column of the pageblock. Is there way we can colspan the whole row and it occupies the full row.
I have tried adding a new row with `<tr> <td>` with `colspan=4` and `colspan=8` but still get the same result

```
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:repeat value="{!CInf}" var="c">

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Tracking Id {!c.ArticleID}">

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Id"></apex:outputLabel>
              <apex:outputText value="{!c.ID}"></apex:outputText>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
          <!-- A few other pageblockSections -->

          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Carrier"></apex:outputLabel>
              <apex:outputText value="{!c.Carrier}"></apex:outputText>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="4" id="pbt">

                 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!c.Events.Eventvalues}" var="d">
                    <apex:column value="{!d.ID}" headerValue="Id"/> 

                    <apex:column value="{!d.EventDescription}" headerValue="Description"/> 
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
              </td>
           </tr>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>


</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 4):

After some trial and error. here is how we can do it

Create one parent pageBlockSection with column="1"
Create two pageBlockSection within this section, one to hold the fields and the other to hold the datatable.

```
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:repeat value="{!CInf}" var="c">

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Tracking Id {!c.ArticleID}" columns="1">
     <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Carrier"></apex:outputLabel>
              <apex:outputText value="{!c.Carrier}"></apex:outputText>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="No of Packets"></apex:outputLabel>
              <apex:outputText value="{!c.nop}"></apex:outputText>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

                 <apex:dataTable value="{!c.Events.Eventvalues}" var="d" styleClass="table table-bordered">

                    <apex:column value="{!d.ArticleID}" headerValue="Article ID"/> 
                    <apex:column value="{!d.EventDateTime}" headerValue="Event Date"/> 
                    <apex:column value="{!d.EventLocation}" headerValue="Location"/> 
                    <apex:column value="{!d.EventDescription}" headerValue="Description"/> 
                </apex:dataTable>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>  
    </apex:pageBlockSection>      


</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just render a new section with the columns attribute set to one with no title. It will layout the way you want, and it will collapse with the previous section when the user collapses it.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working.. when i collapse the previous section the datatable section is visible

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is very simple you can create one more pageblocksection inside another pageblocksection here is the sample code for you

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="1" collapsible="true">
<apex:pageBlockSection   columns="2">
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.Contacts}" var="item">

            <apex:column value="{!item.name}"/> 

        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I hope i answered your question, let me know if you need more help

Comment: This section doesnt extend to the full width of the pageblock. Its restricted to one half of the pageblock